# how to represent an empty field in yaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I am working with fixtures on rails and I want one of the fixture fields to be blank.

Example:

```
two:
name: test
path: - I want this blank but not to act as a group heading.
test: 4
```

But, I do not know how to leave `path:` blank without it acting as a group title.  Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YAML files are based on indentation. Once you actually have correct indentation it will read everything at the same level as siblings.

```
two:
  name: test
  path: 
  test: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Google [says](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-talk-google/browse_thread/thread/f8b1635528665a85) the following should work:

```
path: \"\"
```